# How to run multiple actions in one gulp task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

How can I run multiple actions in one gulp task? The following doesn't work as things seem to run out of order and cause all kinds of strange errors. I've tried `event-stream`'s `merge` like in [How to perform multiple gulp commands in one task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713118/how-to-perform-multiple-gulp-commands-in-one-task) but that doesn't seem to work with del.

I know I can divide it into multiple tasks and use the `run-sequence` plugin, but like in the linked question I don't want to bloat my Gulpfile with tasks that will never be run individually and don't make sense outside of a given context.

```
gulp.task('task', function() {

    del('....');

    gulp.src('....')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('....'));

    gulp.src('....')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('....'));

});
```

Comment: But why not `run-sequence`? If you care about "bloating Gulpfile" you can create additional files and `require` them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign your streams into variables and then run them together with `es.merge` (or you can use [merge-stream](https://github.com/grncdr/merge-stream) if you don't need all of event stream). As for running with `del`, have a look at setting up a dependent task for doing your clean operation:

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md

```
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
  del([
    'dist/report.csv',
    // here we use a globbing pattern to match everything inside the `mobile` folder
    'dist/mobile/**',
    // we don't want to clean this file though so we negate the pattern
    '!dist/mobile/deploy.json'
  ], cb);
});
```

You can then define your other task like this:

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('task', ['clean'], function () {
    var someOperation = gulp.src('./').pipe(gulp.dest('out'));
    var someOtherOperation = gulp.src('./assets').pipe(gulp.dest('out/assets'));

    return merge(someOperation, someOtherOperation);
});
```

This will do the clean first, wait until finished, then run your other operations.